# Slicing and then polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace  Q20
{

//Base Class

class Base
{
    //Add some context to remove posting errors lol
public:
    Base(Base *b = NULL)
    {
        m_b = b;
    }
    Base *m_b;
    virtual void func()
    {
        cout << endl << "B";
        if(m_b)
        {
            m_b->func();
        }
        else
        {
            m_b = (Base *)1;
        }
        return;
    }
};

//Derived 1 Class

class D1 : public Base
{
    //Add some context to remove posting errors lol
public:
    D1(Base *b = NULL)
    {
        m_b = b;
    }
    void func(Base *b)
    {
        cout << endl << "D1";
        m_b->func();
    }
};

//Derived 2 Class

class D2 : public Base
{
    //Add some context to remove posting errors lol
public:
    D2(Base *b = NULL)
    {
        m_b = b;
    }
    void func()
    {
        cout << endl << "D2";
        m_b->func();
    }
};

//Derived 3 Class

class D3 : public Base
{
    //Add some context to remove posting errors lol
public:
    D3(Base *b = NULL)
    {
        m_b = b;
    }
    void func()
    {
        cout << endl << "D3";
        m_b->func();
    }
};

void Q20()
{
    Base *obj = new D2(new D1(new D3(new Base)));

    // The above is the confusing part is there any slicing occurring above and what
    // is going to be the call sequence below...

    obj->func();
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
};

//Posting question is tough
int main()
{
    Q20::Q20();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of code. Could you post a [SSCC Example](http://sscce.org)? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Also, your code throws a warning about `void func(Base *b)` - are you sure it should not be `void func()`?

Comment: The warning must have been about the Base function getting hidden.My question is with void func(Base *b) only..

Comment: I mean whats going to be  the call sequence of func and why and is there any conversions/slicing occurring ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is going to be the call sequence below...

Let's look at it:

```
Base *obj = new D2(...);

obj->func();
```

Well, `D2` overloads `virtual func()` from `Base`, so, it will be called first and `D2` will be printed.

```
D2(new D1(...))
```

There is no overloaded `virtual func()` function in `D1`, so, `Base::func()` will be called and `B` will be printed.

```
D1(new D3(...))
```

`D3` has overloaded function, so, `D3::func()` will be called and `D3` will be printed.

```
D3(new Base)
```

Finally, `B` will be printed. So, full output:

```
D2
B
D3
B
```

Comment: Why should something like this compile at all ?

  D3 * d3 = new D3(new Base);

Comment: @user2468313, Why is this shouldn't?

Comment: Because passing a base object to a derived object does not compile..

like

        D3 d3;
        Base b;
        d3 = b;

Comment: `D3` has no constructor with no arguments at least.